# Jquery get value of text box next to a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form with multiple radio buttons and text boxes.
Each Text box is next to radio button like below:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="correct_answer_id">
                                Correct
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <label for="answer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer 2</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[]"  placeholder="Answer"  required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

There are several radio button and text box pair like above in the form.
On click of the radio button, i want to get whatever has been written in the corresponding text box

i am trying to use Jquery's next() function like below:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                {

                   console.log($(this).next('input[type="text"]').val());
                   
                }
            });
```

But my log shows undefined. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : find parent div of radio and do `next().next()` to get input box `div` and then find input box to get value.

**NOTE** - You need not to check `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` as when you click on radio button it will get checked always.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
var value =  $(this).closest('.radio').next().next('.col-sm-10').find('input[type=text]').val();
  console.log(value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code using parents();  see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5dnogh2/)

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
               console.log($(this).parents('div.radio').next().next('div.col-sm-10').find('input[type="text"]').val());

            }
        });
```

Comment: you need not to check `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` as when you click a radio button it will get checked always.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the value that you want submitted in the `value` attribute of your `input` elements.

e.g. `<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_id" value="correct">`

Your click handler would change to:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    console.log($(this).val());
  }
});
```

If there's some value that you don't want to place in the value attribute then it's still best to have a reference to the value in the input element instead of relying on a particular document layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked'))
         {
        console.log($(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('input[type="text"]').val());

          }
      });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxv7hLpa/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the html a little, here is a different approach http://jsfiddle.net/xa9cjLd9/1/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radio">
        <label data-for='answer[]'>
            <input type="radio" name="correct_answer_id" />Correct</label>
    </div>
    <label for="answer" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[]" placeholder="Answer" required />
    </div>
</div>


$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var data = $(this).closest('label').attr('data-for');

        console.log($('input[name=' + '"' + data + '"' + ']').val());

    }
});
```

Just Define a data attribute to the label , which contains the name of the related input.